# sql query column names based on where clause

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to run a sql query from 1 table where I want the data in each resulting column to be based on a different where clause.

Example:

I have a table called messages with columns called type, size, country

Values for type include email and sms.

Values for size are integers.

I want to create a view that has 3 columns: country, sms, email.  Then, I'd like to show the sum of sizes of emails and sms per country.

I think I need a where clause for the column headings, but I can't figure out how to do this.

I'm trying to do something like:

```
select country, sum(size) 
where type = 'sms' as "SMS", sum(size) 
where type = 'email' as "Email"
from messages table
group by country
```

I hope the logic of what I'm trying to accomplish is clear.  I can't figure out the syntax.  Can someone help?  Thanks!

Note: db is postgressql.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation with `case` expressions like so:

```
select 
    country
  , sum(case when type='email' then size else 0 end) as email
  , sum(case when type='sms' then size else 0 end) as sms
from messages
group by country
```

Comment: Thank you.  Solved my issue!!